# Find all rows which have different values in the columns of a Pandas DataFrame (time series)

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Let's assume I have a pandas DataFrame in Python which shows the **name of the business unit leader for different units over time**. It could look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrKaC.jpg)
and can be recreated like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = pd.DataFrame({'Boss_January': ['Nina', 'Lena', 'Max', np.NaN], 'Boss_February': ['Nina', 'Emilia','Max','Leonie'],'Boss_March':['Nina','Lena','Mark','Leonie']})
```

**I would like to find the units where there has been a change in the business unit leader, i.e. rows where the values across the different columns aren't all the same.**

The result should include Unit 1, Unit 2 and Unit 3 because of changes in the unit leader (and missing value), but exclude Unit 0.

Since the real DataFrame has much more columns, I don't want to check all the values by iterating through the rows and checking if  *Boss_January==Boss_February==Boss_March*.

Comment: df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).nunique() == 1, axis = 1)

if you want the list of indices: df[df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).nunique() == 1, axis = 1)].index

Comment: It would help to provide your data in the form of easily copyable code. Also are those `np.NaN` values, or the string `'NaN'`

Comment: You are right, I've edited my post. Still new to stackoverflow, so thanks for the feedback!

Comment: d[d.apply(lambda x: len(x.unique(dropna=False))!=1, axis=1)]  if NaNs should be counted as a change in leadership. thanks, Brian Joseph :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for equality with the first series, test all values are `True`, then take the negative:

```
res = df[~df.eq(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(1)]

print(res)

  Boss_February Boss_January Boss_March
1        Emilia         Lena       Lena
2           Max          Max       Mark
3        Leonie          NaN     Leonie
```

If you just need indices, subsetting the dataframe is not required:

```
bools = ~df.eq(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(1)
idx = bools[bools].index

print(idx)

Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` with `axis=1` to aggregate the columns and require that the there is more than one `unique` element in all the columns like:

```
d[d.apply(lambda x: len(x.unique())!=1, axis=1)]
```

Comment: In case other people are interested what this answer results in: It gives a True/False for each row :)